# T-SQL Pass back table with dynamic number of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 where I would like to pass back a table with data in it where the number of columns may vary depending on certain conditions.

I could create a table like this and insert data into it but it would always be static:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: You can use table variables.... Declare Table @MyTableVar ...    An alternative is if you know you only need one record then you can just do a raw select with variables.  Also user defined functions can return tables..

Comment: You need to create table per data insert ???

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic query :

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    set @query = 'CREATE TABLE Persons
    (
    @cols
    );'

    execute(@query)
```